# Convert int datatype to string datatype c# access database

Tags: c#, database, winforms

i created Windows Application form my project and there is a problem that i am facing right now.
The problem is: i already had an array of textboxes, and wanted to connect those database textboxes, however, i cannot get the data because the data that i want to connect is int datatype.

There are 2 Form that i has been created, one is for Login Form, for the Login Form, the database is string, so the autocomplete is working. The second one is Second Form, for the Second Form, the database is int, so the autocomplete is not working.

My Question is: How do i convert int datatype to string datatype?

Here is my code for Second Form:

```
string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

    private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxCodeContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Code] FROM [Data] ORDER BY [Code] ASC", conn);
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
    codesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code")))); // This line is not working
    }

//****TextBox for Code****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxCodeContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(25, 150 + (y * 25));

                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteCustomSource = codesCollection;

                dReader.Close();
                conn.Close();

                Controls.Add(textBoxCodeContainer[0][y]);
            }
```

**edit:** data type for code is number, field size is long integer and the format is 0000.. zero behind replaced with number "1", "2" and so on.

**edit**:
******Complete Code*****

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Sell_System
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        private Form1 firstForm;
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxCodeContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxQuantityContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxDescContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxSubTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
            : this()
        {
            this.firstForm = firstForm;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var int num = 10;

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Code] FROM [Data] ORDER BY [Code] ASC", conn);
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
                codesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code"))));
                //codesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(num);
            }

            if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = "Code:";
                label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
                label2.Text = "Welcome to the Selling System.";
                label2.Location = new Point(600, 0);
                label3.Text = "Quantity:";
                label3.Location = new Point(155, 125);
                label4.Text = "Description:";
                label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
                label5.Text = "Sub Total on Rp:";
                label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
                label6.Text = "Total on Rp:";
                label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
                label7.Text = "Total on Rp:";
                label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
            }

            else if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "Kode:";
                label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
                label2.Text = "Selamat datang di Selling System.";
                label2.Location = new Point(600, 0);
                label3.Text = "Banyaknya:";
                label3.Location = new Point(145, 125);
                label4.Text = "Keterangan:";
                label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
                label5.Text = "Sub Total di Rp:";
                label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
                label6.Text = "Total di Rp:";
                label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
                label7.Text = "Total di Rp:";
                label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
            }

            //****TextBox for Code****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxCodeContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(25, 150 + (y * 25));

                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteCustomSource = codesCollection;

                dReader.Close();
                conn.Close();

                Controls.Add(textBoxCodeContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Quantity****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxQuantityContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(125, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Description****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxDescContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxDescContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxDescContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(750, 50);
                textBoxDescContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(225, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxDescContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Sub Total****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxSubTotalContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(975, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Total****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxTotalContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(1150, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxTotalContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Total All****
            TextBox textBoxAllTotal = new TextBox();
            textBoxAllTotal.Size = new Size(175, 50);
            textBoxAllTotal.Location = new Point(1150, 575);

            Controls.Add(textBoxAllTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant believe for one second you have bothered to google this before posting a question on here...

Comment: You say that the line `   codesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code"))));` is not working. What is not working here (assuming the Code field is an integer and not null)

Comment: @Steve: i mean, not working is the autocomplete for int datatype is not working, that code when i trace gave me autos (so it is means there is no error) right?

Comment: The AutoCompleteStringCollection requires strings not ints. So I still cannot understand where is your problem. If you start typing a digit in your textbox, the autocomplete works or not?

Comment: no, the autocomplete is not works when i type a digit in my textbox, but when i change the code to: 
"OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Username] FROM [Member] ORDER BY [Username] ASC", conn); <-- this is the table called Member where inside of it are string type

and change this code too to:
"CodesCollections.Add(drReader.getString(0)), the autocomplete for string type is working

Answer (score 1):

> My Question is: How do i convert int datatype to string datatype?

```
string s = Convert.ToString(yourIntvalue);
```

Comment: i already tried that code, and it is not working, and my value is on database, so how do i fill up that (yourintvalue)

Comment: why not `yourIntValue.ToString()` ?

Comment: codesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code")));

Comment: @EhsanUllah: no, i already tried the code that you gave me, before i post on this forum, and it is not working either

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra what does dReader.GetOrdinal("Code") returns you?

Comment: what do you mean by returns? you mean the what is the message after i trace on the some code?

Comment: i mean is it returning you a string value you are looking for?

Comment: that is your problem. is your string name correct like is it really code?Try dReader.GetString("Code")

Comment: ehm, correct me if i am wrong, but code is number (i set it as number), and the code is getstring.
and GetString is required int ordinal, inside the bracket, not string.
and when i already tried the dReader.GetString(0), the application run, but the Second Form runs blank (nothing inside it)

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra can you tell me any sample value of your code?

Comment: i will give you the full code of my program on Second Form, send me your email

Comment: @EhsanUllah: i already do like this:

int num = 10;

while(drReader.read())
{
   codesCollection.add(Convert.ToString(num));
}

and everything is work perfectly, but now i want to know how to access the codes that i have in database, to appear like the top?

Comment: @EhsanUllah: refer to the my question on the top, i already attach the complete code for Second Form on there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 dReader.GetString("Code");
```

So

```
while (dReader.Read())
{
    codesCollection.Add(dReader.GetString("Code"));
}
```

[OleDbDataReader.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring.aspx)

> Gets the value of the specified column as a string.

Comment: it gave me several errors, which are: "cannot convert string type to int type", and "the best overloaded method for "dbdatareader.getstring(int) has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use CODE as string in all you code, why not changing it from the query?

"SELECT DISTINCT  CStr([Code]) FROM [Data] ORDER BY [Code] ASC"

ACCESS supports some VBscript so CStr would do the trick. Donig this way, the DBReader will treat CODE as string